# Domestic to international at JFK

Tags: luggage, airport-security, short-connections, jfk

I have a flight from Raleigh-Durham via JFK/New York to Incheon, South Korea. It's JetBlue from RDU to JFK and Asiana from JFK to ICN. I only have 2 hours layover in New York and I was worried about making it on time. I know JetBlue and Asiana have a codeshare so I assume that my bags will just be transferred to the international flight at JFK without me having to check them in again. However, I am concerned with travel among the terminals.

Is there secure travel between the terminals so I don't have to leave, check in, and go through security again at the international terminal? Or do I have to do that?

Comment: You probably don't have to check in, but you probably do have to change terminals, which means going through security screening again.

Comment: Could you edit your question so it's comprehensible to people who haven't memorized every airport code in the world?

Comment: I taken the liberty of changing the layover to New York/JFK, instead of what you had, Raleigh Durham.

Comment: Asiana and jetBlue interline, but I do not believe they codeshare.

Answer (score 3):

In order to go between terminals 5 and 4, you'll have to take the AirTrain which means leaving the post-security area. That said, 2 hours should be more than enough time to leave your gate, take the train, and go through security and catch your second flight. I wouldn't be concerned unless your flight gets delayed.

Disclaimer: I've not been through JFK too many times so it may get more crowded than I've seen it.